# Error when setting up deegree 3.4.0

Tags: deegree

I set up deegree 3.4.0 with Tomcat 8 and JDK 8.x by copying the WAR file to the webapps folder as described in the documentation. After that I tried to open the service console at localhost:8080/deegree-webservices-3.4.0 and got the following error message:

```
An Error Occurred:
Cant instantiate class: org.deegree.console.webservices.ServicesBean.
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I see Deegree 3.4.0 is new and they do send users to GIS SE (https://www.deegree.org/community) but not sure there is a lot of GIS.SE users that have used this software yet. according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291010/implementing-a-managed-javabean-throws-an-error-cant-instantiate-class it might be a typo from French to English.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are using Apache Tomcat 8.5+ with a TCK verified JDK 8 such as Oracle JDK or Zulu. 
Check your environment with:

```
./catalina.sh version
```

or on Windows:

```
catalina.bat version
```

Finally check the following QA posted at github: https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/issues/510

Comment: The error `Cant instantiate class: org.deegree.console.webservices.ServicesBean.` also appears when deegree web services is running on Apache Tomcat 9 with Java SE 9/10/11. So for deegree web services 3.4 ensure that Oracle or Open JDK 8 is installed and configured for Apache Tomcat. See the [deegree support matrix](https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/wiki/End-of-Life-and-Support-Matrix) for more information about the supported Java SE and Tomcat version.